# Product of disjoint cycles and product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

$\alpha=(3412)(245)\in S_5$ and I have to 1) write this as a product of disjoint cycles, 2) write this as a product of transpositions.

1) I can do thing by following where the elements go in the two permutations. I obtain $\alpha=(21)(453)$ this seems to be correct.

2) How do I write this as a product of transpostions? I have trouble seeing how this is possible, seeing that $\alpha$ has a three length cycle within it.

How do I do 2)?

Comment: $\alpha=(2\ 1)(4\ 5)(5\ 3)$

Comment: @bof I'm an idiot

Edit: thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a permutation is known as a product of *disjoint* (hence commuting) cycles, one can work in parallel and so it suffices to know how to write a cycle as a product of transpositions.   To avoid a clutter of subscripts, I'll give  an example:

$(7413625) = (75)(72)(76)(73)(71)(74)$

(In each of these transpositions 7 occurs, the other numbers accompanying 7 are taken in the reverse order to the given cycle)

Comment: That's highly convenient, thanks!

Comment: So there are multiple products of transpositions? Doing the product of transpostions off of $(3412)(245)$ gives us $(32)(31)(34)(25)(24)$ which works and doing it off of $(21)(453)$ gives us $(21)(43)(45)$ which also works.

Comment: @Permute Indeed. Notice, however, that you can only write $\alpha$ as a product of an odd number of transpositions.

Comment: @Taylor Does such a property imply $\alpha$ is odd? That was actually another part of the past exam question.

Comment: @Taylor Sorry I should restate my question, does $\alpha$ being odd or even, mean that it has an odd or even number of transpositions in its product of transpositions. Or does it refer to something else?

Comment: @Permute That is precisely what it refers to.

Comment: If the permutation is written as a product of cycles--**disjoint (commuting) or not**--it suffices to write each cycle as a product of transpositions. By the way I've never understood why the factorization $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)=(1\ 7)(1\ 6)(1\ 5)(1\ 4)(1\ 3)(1\ 2)$ is so much more popular than $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)=(1\ 2)(2\ 3)(3\ 4)(4\ 5)(5\ 6)(6\ 7).$ There must be some big advantage to using the former; I wish I knew what it was.

Comment: @bof: You are right, it does not matter if the cycles commute or not. When they commute the resulting expression as product of transpositions would be minimal.  About the two ways, later one seems slightly easier to remember. Don't know why the former became popular.

Answer (score 0):

As Product of disjoint cycles: $\alpha=(3412)(245)=(12)(345)$

As Product of transpositions: $\alpha=(3412)(245)=(32)(31)(34)(25)(24)$